# How to create a variable in R based on another dataset of different length

Tags: variables, dataset, conditional-statements, creation

I'm trying to create a variable `STATE`, which is present in another dataset of different length than mine.

Both objects have a state coding variable `GESTFIPS`. So, I just want to let R check if the `GESTFIPS`match and then create the variable `STATE` in my dataset accordingly.

I tried:

```
> state_1865_base$STATE[state_1865_base$GESTFIPS==urate2$GESTFIPS] < - 
+ urate2$STATE[state_1865_base$GESTFIPS==urate2$GESTFIPS]
```

And got the error message:

```
Error in -urate2$STATE[state_1865_base$GESTFIPS == urate2$GESTFIPS] : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In state_1865_base$GESTFIPS == urate2$GESTFIPS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In state_1865_base$GESTFIPS == urate2$GESTFIPS :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

My Dataset looks like (132990 obs. of 117 variables):

```
data.frame':    132990 obs. of  117 variables:
 $ IDENTIFIER          : chr  "20030100013280" "20030100013344" "20030100013352" "20030100013848" ...
 $ AGE                 : num  60 41 26 36 51 32 44 21 33 39 ...
 $ MALE                : num  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BLACK               : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ MARRIED             : num  1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ NUM_CHILD           : num  0 2 0 2 2 1 1 1 3 4 ...
 $ HV_CHILD            : num  0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ AGE_YOUNGEST        : num  NA 0 NA 9 14 2 9 14 3 4 ...
 $ CHILD_4             : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ CHILD_5             : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ GRADE               : num  17 13 13 12 17 16 12 13 13 13 ...
 $ SPOUSE_EMP          : num  0 1 0 1 0 1 1 NA 1 0 ...
 $ SPOUSE_WORKHOURS    : num  NA 50 NA 40 NA 40 50 NA 40 NA ...
 $ WORKING             : num  1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ UNEMP               : num  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ RETIRED             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DISABLED            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ STUDENT             : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HOMEMAKER           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ WORK_PART           : num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ HH_INCOME_03        : num  660 200 200 NA NA ...
 $ WAGE_03             : num  22 6.67 16.67 NA NA ...
 $ WAGE_03_ALT         : num  22 NA 12.5 NA NA NA NA 9.5 14 12 ...
 $ YEAR                : num  2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 ...
 $ DATASET             : num  2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 ...
 $ INTERVIEW_DAY       : num  5 6 6 4 4 4 1 2 6 4 ...
 $ INTERVIEW_DATE      : Date, format: "2003-01-03" "2003-01-04" "2003-01-04" "2003-01-02" ...
 $ GESTFIPS            : num  6 6 6 13 21 21 22 26 27 34 ...
[list output truncated]
```

This is the dataset `urate`, where the states are stored. (204 obs. of 6 variables)

```
STATE GESTFIPS NOBS TWOYEAR UNEMP       URATE
   AL   1      434    1     0.05392952  5.19585
   AL   1      288    2     0.02666941  3.63750
   AL   1      266    3     0.03848163  4.24585
   AL   1      248    4     0.11545039  9.59580
   AK   2       62    1     0.07917716  7.52915
   AK   2       41    2     0.12782212  6.70415
   AK   2       38    3     0.00000000  6.25835
```

Comment: What happens when you change the assignment operator from `< -` to `<-`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state_1865_base$STATE <- urate2$STATE[match(state_1865_base$GESTFIPS, urate2$GESTFIPS)]` should work.

**EDIT:** My original, incorrect answer was

> It looks as though you are using `< -` for assignment. If you use `<-`
>   instead, I think that your code will work.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This was just a editing problem here in stackoverflow, but the code was typed in correctly. The error persists. Thank you.

Comment: My mistake. On closer look, the error message is informative: you have 132990 observations in `state_1865_base` and 204 in `urate2`. You're getting an error because 132990 / 204 isn't an integer. And it's good that you're getting an error, because if 132990 / 204 were in an integer, you would be getting a result that you don't want. Try something like `state_1865_base$STATE <- urate2$STATE[match(state_1865_base$GESTFIPS, urate2$GESTFIPS)]`. Does that work?

Comment: It worked perfeclty fine. Thank your for the explanation. Please update the answer so I can promote it. Do you have also Stata knowledge?

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry that I don't know much about Stata. (Wish that I knew more.)

Comment: do you know something about first difference regression with plm in R?

Comment: Not really. The place to start may be [the basic plm vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plmPackage.html). For what it's worth, when I just need to run any kind of linear fixed-effects regression, I now rely on the "estimatr" package, which I've found easier to use and less buggy.

Comment: I've done some first difference regressions with plm. But now I need some weighted versions... and the package doesn't seem to have this option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206549/discussion-between-user697473-and-econ-spectre).